# WPF -MVVM : Checkbox Check Change in RadGridView

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik

Here is my Checkbox in RadGridView which is not implemented in MVVM. I would like to implement this MVVM.

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Delete" >
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsDeleted, Mode=TwoWay }" Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked"  Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked">
        </CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
```

I used interaction triggers but the command is not getting fired. How can I do this ?

```
   <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Delete" Width="60">
    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" IsChecked="{Binding IsDeleted, Mode=TwoWay}" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Checked">
                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DiagramChecked}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </CheckBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>                   
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger seems fine. Presumably, your DiagramChecked is in another DataContext than Context CheckBox is binding to (where IsDeleted is placed). Check if Output window reports any errors. 
My assumtpion is that it is refering to wrong DataContext. Try to bind to DataContext of some root element in which DataContext the DiagramChecked command is placed.

```
 <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=SomeType},Path=DataContext. DiagramChecked}" />
```

Comment: DiagramChecked is in the same class what IsDeleted property?

Comment: if checkbox is checked, IsDeleted Property is true